# EF6 vs2013 32bit to DB Oracle 11.2g 64bit

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6, odp.net, odac

Can I access the database oracle 11.2g 64bit with Visual-Studio-2013 on Windows 32bit which use the EF6, ODAC 12c Release 3 using the method Database First? because after I try I get an error when it will generate the model db

I have the following configured in my Web.config:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
             type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  </configSections>
```

```
  <entityFramework> 
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
```

and this is the error display:
[error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kasNS.jpg)

Comment: Yes, architecture of Client (i.e. ODAC) and architecture of database are completely independent from each other. `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess` works for both 32 bit and 64 bit applications.

Comment: Did you make those web.config entries manually? If you did, I would suggest you first allow ODP.NET to create them automatically  by using the nuget package to make sure the values are correct. Any mistake in there will lead to the kinds of errors you are seeing.